# ListView not updating

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android. could anyone tell me what is it that i am doing wrong. My listView won't update!
I want a listview with images in it.
I shall explain the flow here
i have an `ImageList.java` as my main class and and `LazyLoader.java` which extends BaseAdapter.
Here the images are retrieved from an xml file stored on my localhost.
What works is this, 
There is no problem with the localhost i used 10.0.2.2 and i get my xml in LogCat.
Everything works without errors in logcat but the view doesnt update.
I guess there is some problem with the way i am thinking about inflate and the way it works. so a good point to start would be to look at `LazyLoader.java`
If things are not clear from the code please let me know i shall add more explanation.

I have followed this tutorial and made changes for `asynctask`
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

**ImageList.java**
This is my onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 try{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
new loadSite().execute();
}
catch(Exception exp){
    Log.e("error", "ERROR RAISED HERE "+exp);
    exp.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

And the Async is here

```
class loadSite extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ImageList.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading websites ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try{
                ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> articlesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

                for(int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
                     HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     Element elm = (Element) nl.item(i);
                     map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(elm, KEY_TITLE));
                     map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(elm, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                     Log.e("URL",parser.getValue(elm, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                     articlesList.add(map);

                }
                list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                //ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ImageList.this,articlesList, R.layout.list_row, new String[] {"list_image"},new int[]{R.id.list_image});
                adapter = new LazyAdapter(ImageList.this,articlesList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            catch(Exception exp){
                Log.e("Error", "EXCEPTION RAISED IN ASYNC "+exp);
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

    return null;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         Log.e("Notify","Dataset change notified");
    }
}
```

The LazyAdapter class is here is here. it extends BaseAdapter
**LazyAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);

    }
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
    HashMap<String,String> article = new HashMap<String, String>();
    article = data.get(position);
    title.setText(article.get(ImageList.KEY_TITLE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(article.get(ImageList.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;

}
```

XML, if anyone needs to see.

**Main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <include layout="@layout/header"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="3dip"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"  
        android:src="@drawable/nature"/>

</LinearLayout>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not initialize a `LazyAdapter` and set it to your `ListView` inside **doInBackground** method, because manipulating views must be done on UI thread and **doInBackground** runs on a separate thread.

Instead, I would suggest you to return `articlesList` (adapter's dataset) from **doInBackground** to the **onPostExecute** method and initialize an adapter and set it to your list inside that same method because **onPostExecute** always runs on UI thread - hence allowing you to manipulate views.

Comment: if i runonuithread won't i get an error? i corrected that sometime ago. i used to get a NetworkOnMainThreadException so that is why did that edit. ImageList is the class that is called when the app start

Comment: I don't know whats happening inside `LazyAdapter` but perhaps you need to fix it too so it performs network operations on a separate thread.

Comment: the getView mentioned above is in LazyAdapter. since it extends BaseAdapter i also have the necessary methods that come with it. It would be great if you could have a look at LazyAdapter in the link i provided above.

Comment: Seems like **getBitmap** method inside `LazyAdapter` needs to be done on a separate thread because its the one which initiates internet connection